# How to expand an UL element containing position relative/absolute children without hardcoded dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm trying to have an element expand based on available space. The element contains images and I'm getting nowhere...

My HTML:

```
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a>
    <img>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

With the following CSS, the `ul` expands full width (ok), but has no height set:

```
ul {
  height: inherit;
  list-style: none outside none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  /* cheating: min-height: 10em; */
}
li {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  list-style: none outside none;
  overflow: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  height: inherit;
  overflow: auto;
  width: inherit;
}
img {
  height: inherit;
  display: table-row-group;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a CSS way to set the height of the `ul` to that of the contained image? I can cheat and set `min-height` on the `ul` but this really isn't an option. `Position` also must remain.

Thanks

Comment: could you explain your usecase a bit more? Why the `position:absolute` have to maintain? And when it have to, can it be moved to another element? Here is my demo of the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/vuw8L/1/

Comment: It will more or less be a slider usimg css3 transitions. The parent must be pos:relative to hide the css transition while the child must be pos:absolute to CSSanimate. I make a fiddle later. Errants to run

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is that you have position absolute set on the inner li. The way to fix this is to add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To the style of the ul

Comment: try removing `height: inherit` @frequent

Comment: thx, but nope. the nested elements have correct dimensions, only the `ul` is .... [my_screen_width]x0 (in my case)

Comment: @frequent change it to `height: auto`

Comment: @frequent can you make a fiddle so I can test

Comment: @frequent why do you need the li to have a position of absolute